# Find unused public members in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class which has 1600 public static members. I must found and delete the unused ones. Is there a way to do it in Eclipse.

Comment: you can delete it. if it generates an error undelete it. how can you detect if something is in use though? deprecation might be a better idea.

Comment: doesn't code expection solve your issue?

Comment: what is code expection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There exists a Eclipse plugin Unused Code Detector (http://www.ucdetector.org/).
It can process a specific file or the entire project, searching for unused members/methods.

Comment: **UCDetector** does not detect the calls to methods from `.xml` files (in case of spring web-flow). So, it shows that the method is not being called from anywhere in the project, but ideally it is being called from web-flow. Is there any way where I can check the calls from web-flow as well apart from other `.java` files?

Comment: @NisargPatil Spring uses reflection to call these methods, there's no way a tool can detect that. Same applies to Struts.

Answer (score 8):

**Ucdetector:** You can install a plugin from this link. It works pretty well we have been using it in all our projects. It generates a html report as well it can mark warnings in eclipse. It helps you find unused classes, methods and variables. Only thing it dosen't do well is finding if a class is used via reflection only or where instance is created via spring. In these cases it still shows that class is unused.

http://ucdetector.sourceforge.net/update

**Another thing you can do to clean up other types of unsed code is** 
GoTo Window>Preferences>Java>Compiler>Error/Warnings

[image]
Now look for uncessary code section and tweak the settings as you desire to cleanup further.

I hope it helps :)